# Passing session variable from PHP using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cordova

I am currently using [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) to make an app. 
As we know, PhoneGap only allow HTML, CSS and JS to be used. Therefore, PHP cannot be used. 
I have researched a bit and I found out that I can just put the PHP file in a remote server and use AJAX to call for the PHP file using the URL of the remote server.

But I cannot find a way to pass a session variable from the PHP to HTML. Passing session variable from PHP to PHP is easy. 
However as there will not be PHP to PHP communication allowed in PhoneGap, I have to use PHP to HTML and then to PHP again. 
Passing the session variable using AJAX back to the HTML might be complicated. This leads me into a dead-end.

Any clues on how to solve this problem? 
 If my explanation about my situation is not that comprehensible, please feel free to comment. 
Thanks.

Comment: Sessions are stored on the server and HTML is client side.
The way I am understanding your question you want the session client side? 
[Maybe use something like this?](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage)

Comment: yeah, I think session in client side will work, as I will need to store the id of the user who just log in. Can we do this using localstorage?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to echo data back from an ajax call.

Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "url_to_file",
      type: "get",
      success: function(data){
            // do stuff with the data      
      },
      error:function(){
          alert("ajax call error");
      }   
});
```

PHP file:

```
<?php
    echo $_SESSION['varible'];
?>
```

I would probably use JSON instead of echoing plain text.